# How to have a back button always go to the previous view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have multiple views, some of which are part of tabBarControllers, and the views are pushing to one view controller called `View2`. When I go back to the view that presented view2, how would I go back to a specific tab in the tab bar instead of going to the first one?

My action for the button that goes back to the first view is

```
-(IBAction)goBackButton:(id)sender
{
    ViewController *firstView = [myStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"view1"];
    [self presentViewController:firstView animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

So ViewController is the class of the first view in the tab bar, and the tabBarController has the identifier "view1"

Comment: Can you explain your question a little more? I may have a good solution, but I'm not sure what you mean by "goes back to the right view, instead of only going back to the same one?"

Comment: @maxGabriel I want to go back to the view that presented view2. There are 7 views that can present the view, I don't know how to go back to the  specific one that presented it.

Comment: You need to use Custom UIBarButtonItem with action event ..

Comment: Just so you know, this could be a poor user experience and may confuse the user if they don't return along the path they've taken within the app.

Comment: @tim you're right. Do you know how to load a specific tab in the tab bar controller? I'll update the question to make more sense

Comment: @tim never mind phil's answer worked. i just had to dismiss the view! im really rusty on my Xcode/obj-c thanks though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `View2` has been **pushed** then your backbuttons action should call:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

If `View2` is a **modal** then your backbuttons action should call:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

And whichever scene called `View2` will reappear for you.